# How to flatten assets listing view (remove subfolders constraint)

Tags: assets, structure

Well I like in the entries listing the possibility to toggle a structure entry type between Structured and List view.
[image]

I d like to do same for my assets because I got a structured assets tree with plenty of subfolders and I want to see also the assets as a listing...
[image]

Is it possible to do that?
(`ElementActions` are only used for triggering action on selected elements)

In resume :
1/ **How to add a button in the main menu bar, beside the search field on the right for example...**
2/ **How to hook into assets listing ? (when button clicked)**